# Shopify email with cPanel Hosting

Tags: dns, shopify, cpanel, dkim

I bought a domain when I created my Shopify page, so currently, everything is hosted & controlled by Shopify.

I have a separate cPanel hosting at Hostinger where I host another webpage. If I were to use this cPanel hosting to serve emails for my Shopify webpage, what would be the best way to do it?

I can add/change DNS records in Shopify, so this works perfectly and I can send/receive emails, BUT adding a DKIM record seems impossible: cPanel generates 2048 bit DKIM while, according to Shopify's support, "2048 bit isn't supported by Shopify."

They seem only to support 1024 bit DKIM. Any suggestion on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The DKIM on your domain should be related to the mail service that your domain will use.
For example, if Shopify mail servers will send the mails, then you should use their DKIM, but if you send your mails via Hostigner or any 3rd party mail provider, then you should ask them to provide you with the correct DKIM that you should place inside your domain's DNS zone.

Comment: Hostinger's cPanel generates 2048 bit DKIM while, according to Shopify's support, "2048 bit isn't supported by Shopify." You can't add this DKIM key to Shopify DNS zone.

Comment: In that case, you can point your domain to Hostinger's nameservers so you can use their DNS zone and at the same time place an "A" record for the domain there to Shopify's IP address. This way, your domain will resolve at Hostinger and use their DNS zone, but at the same time the domain will be still resolving at Shopify to serve the website from there.